# Spring data JPA no of insertions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Service Class

```
@Service
public class TableService {

    @Autowired
    private Table1Repo t1Repo;

    public void saveTable1(Table1 t,int a, Table1 t2){
        t1Repo.save(t);
        int x = 10/a; 
        t1Repo.save(t2);
    }
}
```

Now in controller when i am passing two different objects of Table1(both created using new), the two rows are inserted in DB.

But If am passing the same object by two ways
a)
 In controller

```
 Table1 t1 = new Table1()
 ... setters
 Table1 t2 = t1

 tableService.saveTable1(t1,10,t2)
```

b) 
 Table1 t1 = new Table1()
 tableService.saveTable1(t1,10,t1)

These both methods are just creating 1 row in DB? why is that?

Table1 Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")
public class Table1 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public Table1() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which JPA provider you are using? also show us the `Table1` entity

Comment: Hibernate, edited the question for Entity

Comment: `equals` and `hashCode` as well please

Comment: I have not overrided them

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - Same object cannot be persisted twice in same session.

Statement `Table1 t2 = t1;` essentially makes the `tableService.saveTable1(t1,10,t2)` same as `tableService.saveTable1(t1,10,t1)`. Hence only one record is persisted as same object reference is used within same session.

Since two object created via `new` keyword has different references thus save corresponding two records in DB.

For persisting same object twice either

- Save them in different session (*might be tricky*)
- Deep clone the original object and save both i.e. original and clone in same session (*recommended*)

Also on side note it is recommended to override `equals` and `hashCode` for entities to avoid any surprises.